# is there a command I can run to disable the “Work” profile?

Tags: automation, work-profiles, digital-wellbeing

I want to disable the Work profile on a schedule using Easer. I know Digital Wellbeing already provides this feature but it doesn't work for me, the app always crashes right when the Work profile is scheduled to turn off.

Comment: I have a quick setting in my Android 10 that toggles Work Profile? Do you not have such a quick setting? Try editing quick settings and see if Work Profile toggle shows up among available tiles.

Comment: @Firelord I also have that tile, unfortunately it doesn't work properly: I can use it to enable Work profile, but not to disable it. Also, what I need is a command I can run with Termux (for instance), because scripting a user-interface action is not as simple as running a command.

Comment: To disable you can do `am stop-user -f WORK_PROFILE_USER_ID`. It works but does not work cleanly -- the work profile apps gets disabled but the app icons don't look greyed out.

Comment: Thank you, guess I can settle for the Work tile for now :3